# Can't add Controller/View with MVC 5 after VS Update 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller, view

After having installed the Update 4, Visual Studio 2013 don't recognize everything related to MVC anymore and a lot of things are underlined in red.
Assemblies such as System.Web.Html.HtmlHelper or System.Web.Mvc are presents in warning messages, but my applications still runs.

The problem is that now, I can't add a new Controller or add a View to a Controller, and this is really problematic when I want for example to generate a Controller with Views using Entity Framework.

I have tried to relaunch the Update4.exe with "Repair" option.
I also have tried to unintsall and reinstall VS2013.

Please answer me if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you became a victim of [MS14-059 windows update](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms14-059). Make sure that you are referencing correct assemblies not from GAC but these that you downloaded via NuGet.